# How is @TransactionTimeout handled by WildFly?

Tags: transactions, timeout, ejb, wildfly

I am wondering how @TranscationTimeout is handled by WildFly, especially when invoking anothers EJB method annotated with @TransactionAttribute but not with @TransactionTimeout itself.

I have searched [WildFly documentation](https://docs.wildfly.org/17/Developer_Guide.html#transaction-timeout), [API Docs](https://docs.jboss.org/ejb3/embedded/api/org/jboss/annotation/ejb/TransactionTimeout.html) and of course googled, but I am not able to find any statements.

Consider the following scenario. We have stateless EJBs A and B.

```java
@Stateless
public class A {

  @Inject
  private B b;

  @TransactionTimeout(unit = TimeUnit.MINUTES, value = 10)
  public void t() {
    b.t();
  }
}

@Stateless
public class B {

  @TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRES_NEW)
  public void t() {
  }
}
```

When invoked by client, I expect:

- A::t runs within a transaction with a timeout of 10 minutes
- B::t runs within a new transaction with the container default timeout (5 minutes in WildFly)
- B::t within A::t runs in its own new transaction with the container default timeout (5 minutes in WildFly)

What happens:

- B::t within A::t runs in its own new transaction with a timeout of 10 minutes

It seems that @TransactionTimeout is inherited to nested EJB methods if they are not annotated with @TransactionTimeout in some way respectively container default is overriden when they are called. Is this behavior wanted? Are there exceptions?

I am running WildFly 10.1.0 with Java 8.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [TransactionTimeout-Annotation](https://github.com/wildfly/jboss-ejb3-ext-api/blob/master/src/main/java/org/jboss/ejb3/annotation/TransactionTimeout.java) states:

"Annotation for specifying the transaction timeout of a newly started transaction when invoking an EJB business method"

That means imO: for a newly started transaction, not for the currently running transaction. Therefore B:t is affected since it starts a new transaction, as possibly is A:t, but only if it is called out of a non transactional context. (default @Requires might mean, that the transaction is already running.)

This would then fit to your observations.

Comment: Thank you for linking the source. I will draw the developers attention to this question.

Comment: "Therefore B:t is affected since it starts a new transaction..." - but B::t is not annotated at all. Therefore i would expect the container default for this method.

Comment: "When invoking an EJB-Businessmethod": B::t() is an EJB-Businessmethod, it is invoked in the annotated method, therefore the Annotation is valid for it. I would even say, it should be valid also for indirectly called EJB-Businessmethods which start new Transactions. I don't see according to the documentation that the Annotation is only valid if the annotated Method itself is called and newly starts a transaction.

Comment: Ahh, I think I got your point and it makes sense. So the container default (global) transaction timeout setting must be applied (1) to new transactions (2) until an EJB method in the calling stack is annotated with @TransactionTimeout which itself starts a new transaction (directly or indirectly) and (3) overrides the setting for the newly started and further new transactions as long as (2) and (3) occour again?

Comment: Yes, in that way I understand the javadoc-comment.